# VBA Copy worksheet (with variable name) from another workbook to the current workbook and rename it in the current workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy, rename, worksheet

I've been trying to figure this out and have several failed attempts. I am attempting to copy (preferably just move) the only worksheet from another workbook into the current workbook amd rename it to "Source" once in the current notebook. The catch is the files are not in the same folder, but both will be open. Also the name of the worksheet to be copied/moved varies on every instance.

I super appreciate any assistance you can provide.

Comment: You will probably need some sort of a custom form to specify these file locations and that is too much to give you in a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: That is not enough information to create rules. Can you post some failed attempts?

Comment: I actually figured it out. It was far more simple than I was making it. I'll post it later as an answer for anyone looking to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Sub move_external_sheet ()
'
        On Error Resume Next
'
    Result = InputBox("What is the name of the tab you want to move?", "Sheet Mover")

```
Windows(Result & ".xls").Activate

Sheets(Result).Select

Sheets(Result).Move After:=Workbooks("Data Converter.xlsm").Sheets(1)

Worksheets(Result).Name = "Source"

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

     Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
```

End Sub